# Access variable set in event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, events

Is there any way to access a variable set in event ?

the code :

```
$scope.$on('event_detail', function (event, args) {
        $scope.id = args;
        console.log($scope.id); // it works

});
console.log($scope.id); // it says undefined
```

If I try to display in console "$scope.id", the console says "undefined".
I want to access the variable out of the function event $scope.$on

my broadcast :

```
$scope.showDetail = function (data) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast("event_detail", data.id_case);
        $location.path("/detailcase/" + data.id_case);
    };
```

Comment: Yes, if the $broadcast/$emit has args: $broadcast(name, args);. What does your $broadcast/$emit look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `$scope.$on` is async so when you call `console.log` outside the event function, `$scope.id` was not set yet.

So you have to do whatever you want to do inside the `$on` function, because then you know for sure that `$scope.id` has been populated;

Comment: Good catch, totally missed that one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are defining a `delegate` here .. no call happened till now ..

```
$scope.$on('event_detail', function (event, args) {
        $scope.id = args;

        // it will work because the $scope.id get populated
        console.log($scope.id); 

});

//$scope.id It is not populated yet .. 
//it will be populated when the broadcast get called
console.log($scope.id);
```

If your code look like something below than it will work...

```
$scope.$on('event_detail', function (event, args) {
        $scope.id = args;
        console.log($scope.id); // it works

});

$rootScope.$broadcast("event_detail", data.id_case); //make the braodcast

console.log($scope.id); // it will be no-more undefined
```